# How to use class inheritance on single table in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working on an .NET web app that handles user profiles. We use SQL Server and EF.

Here is my view (I only show some columns for brevity):

```
Profile
---------------
EmployeeNumber (not null)
Name (null)
HireDate (null)
POST_ID (null)
Station (null)
```

The thing is, Department A uses POST_ID and not Station while Department B uses Station but not POST_ID. So for my models, I thought I would create a base class with the common fields and then inherit department specific classes from it and include the department specific fields.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeNumber {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime HireDate {get;set;}
}

[Table("Profile")]
public class DeptA_Profile : Profile
{
    public int POST_ID {get;set;}
}

[Table("Profile")]
public class DeptB_Profile : Profile
{
    public string Station {get;set;}
}
```

However, when I run my code I get the following error:

```
The entity types 'DeptA_Profile' and 'DeptB_Profile' cannot share table 'Profile'
because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one
foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.
```

So I am obviously not doing what I am trying to do in the correct manner. Can I get some help with this? I am open to changing my models if there is a better way.

Comment: Please look for "TPH inheritance".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: @GertArnold I have been researching tph but everything I find is for code first. That is not an option in this case. Do you know if this is possible in db first?

Comment: Keep in mind that classes generated by EF are partial classes. In recent projects, I was adding functionality by extending these partial classes.